# How to replace file strings with regexp in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to replace the specific numbers and use this command:

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]\{12\}/ /g' file.log
```

but nothing happens. As U can see this expression should replace all numeric occurrences with size of 12 digits, globally and replace it with space. I found out that the {, } symbols should be escaped - weird. 
It doesn't work. 
Please help.

Comment: Works for me. Can you show a sample input?

Comment: It works fine for me. Which Linux version are you using?

Comment: when I type `echo 1224512561234 | sed -e 's/[0-9]\{12\}/ /g'` i got response ` 4`. It seem to me to be correct.

Comment: As others have pointed out it appears to work fine.. That won't edit the content of the file itself though. If that's what you're trying to do you can try the `-i` option for sed see `man sed` (http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed)